# OpenCV Python HoughLines Transformation get the rectangle points to crop the original image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

Is there anyway to get the rectangle points from the HoughLines Transformation results and apply the crop point to original image to get the cropped image. I have copied the code form the documentation.  The idea is to extract the document from an image.  Below is the result from the HoughLines Transformation and I required the intersection point to crop the image.

[image]

```
"""
@file hough_lines.py
@brief This program demonstrates line finding with the Hough transform
"""
import sys
import math
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main(argv=[]):
    
    default_file = "/Users/apple/Downloads/Unknown-4"
    filename = argv[0] if len(argv) > 0 else default_file
    # Loads an image
    src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(filename), cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    # Check if image is loaded fine
    if src is None:
        print ('Error opening image!')
        print ('Usage: hough_lines.py [image_name -- default ' + default_file + '] \n')
        return -1
    
    
    dst = cv.Canny(src, 50, 200, None, 3)
    
    # Copy edges to the images that will display the results in BGR
    cdst = cv.cvtColor(dst, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cdstP = np.copy(cdst)
    
    lines = cv.HoughLines(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 150, None, 0, 0)
    
                   
    
    if lines is not None:
        for i in range(0, len(lines)):
            rho = lines[i][0][0]
            theta = lines[i][0][1]
            a = math.cos(theta)
            b = math.sin(theta)
            x0 = a * rho
            y0 = b * rho
            pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000*(-b)), int(y0 + 1000*(a)))
            pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000*(-b)), int(y0 - 1000*(a)))
            cv.line(cdst, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)
    
    
    linesP = cv.HoughLinesP(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 10)
    
    if linesP is not None:
        for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
            l = linesP[i][0]
            cv.line(cdstP, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)
    
    #cv.imshow("Source", src)
    #plt.imshow(src)

    plt.imshow(cdstP)
    #plt.imshow(cdstP)
    
    


    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: did you get the solution

Comment: No I dint't get it...  @rcvaram

Comment: can you share the original image

Comment: it's added now @rcvaram.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7G4i.jpg

Comment: did you get the solution –